# ERROR 999999: Error executing function - Failed to execute (CopyRaster)

Tags: raster, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, error-999999, sderaster

> ERROR 999999: Error executing function
>   Unexpected operation
>   No spatial reference exists

This is a fragment from my log report:

> ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>   Database user name and current user schema do not match. [workspace.admin.StreetLightOutages]
>   No spatial reference exists.
>   DBMS table not found
>   Failed to execute (CopyRaster).

I can't import a raster to sde schema using another user (not sde user).
The used user has all privileges (admin privileges) but an error occurred while import  raster dataset to postgresql database using ArcGIS for desktop.
While importing the same raster dataset to the same database using sde user, the operation performed successfully.

Can you help me please whats is wrong in my actions?

Answer (score 1):

Make your user the Owner(DBO) of the database and test.  If it works then there is something wrong with your user and it exactly what it says.  The Schema name and the user names need to match.  If you use the SQL tools and dig in to the User and Schema sections you will see that they don't match.  Your Schema will probably say dbo and your user is something else.  FYI you will need to remove your user from the DB before making them DBO.  Once you find that it works, use the Arccatalog tools to make the user in the DB not the SQl tools.